# How WhatsApp for Web gets data from app

Tags: java, android, ios, websocket, whatsapp

Does app send data directly to web client? Or data goes through web server to web client?

I don't want to know about how web client gets authenticate.

What happen if web client send image/text message from PC.

1. Web client > web server > App > WhatsApp server > destination app.

Or something like this?
2. Web Client > App > WhatsApp Server > destination.

Or what happen if image/message sent from app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Web client uploads the file or any type of data to server, then server  sends a callback to destination and destination app downloads it.

Comment: Then how the mobile app gets an image?

Comment: Downloads it from server.

Comment: What's the overall architecture is it webapi websocket?